# JavaScript input text box adding plus number

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding the add sign in JavaScript I'm a bit confused on this. I have this input text box which I will be input as 50 and it will add plus 50 . My result in adding the numbers which for example I input 50 the result is 5050 which is totally wrong. Can someone help me on this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>activity 2</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function computeSalary(){
    var salaryData = document.form1.salary.value;
    var salary1 = salaryData  + 50;
    document.form1.newSalary.value = salary1;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="form1">
    Enter the daily salary:
    <input type="text" name="salary" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Compute" onClick="computeSalary();" /><br />
    <br />
    The new salary: <input type="text" name="newSalary" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
var salary1 = parseInt(salaryData)  + 50; // Use parseInt or parseFloat
```

The reason is that JavaScript will coerce strings and integers into strings. So your integer 50 is converted to a string and then concatenated.

Comment: Sorry, my screen jumped while I was editing my question and it edited yours by accident. I rolled your last revision back.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string value you're getting, which is being concatenated to your value, to a number by simply adding a plus sign:

```
var salary1 = +salaryData  + 50;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vh9gQ/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the value you got from the input control to float or integer before adding it using the + operator. The + operator will convert both operands to a same type before adding both operands. This is the primary reason why you got 5050 because the 50 of type int got converted to string.

use this code:

```
function computeSalary(){
    var salaryData = document.form1.salary.value;
    var salary1 = parseFloat(salaryData)  + 50;
    document.form1.newSalary.value = salary1;
}
```